# I am not able to print all the prime numbers using this logic

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int num,i,n,count=0;
    cout<<"Enter the range";
    cin>>num;
    for(n=2;n<=num;n++){
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
            if(n%i==0)
            count++;
        }
            if(count==2){
            cout<<"The prime numbers are as follows "<<n;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am using this logic right now. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code. You were not resetting count to 0 as you are checking if number is arriving in its own and in and table of 1.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int num,i,n,count=0;
    cout<<"Enter the range";
    cin>>num;
    for(n=2; n<= num;n++){
        count = 0;
        for(i=1; i <= n; i++){
            if(n % i == 0)
                count++;
        }
        if(count==2){
            cout<<"The prime numbers are as follows "<< n << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not resetting `count` to `0`. That is why, the below `if block` executes once.

```
if(count==2){
   cout<<"The prime numbers are as follows "<<n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so let us start with finding if a single given number is prime.

The number n is prime only if 2,3,4,...,n-1 do not divide n.
For example, 13 is prime because 2,3,4,...,11 do not divide 13.

So the snippet might look like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int num;
    cout << "Enter the number: ";
    cin >> num;

    bool isPrime = true;
    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if(num%i == 0){
            // Not a prime number
            isPrime = false;
        }
    }
    if(isPrime) {
        cout << num << " is a prime number\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I looped through all the numbers from 2 to n-1, then I checked if they divide num.
I created a boolean called isPrime(which stores if the number is prime). The value of isPrime is initialized with true.

If at any point a number divides n, we change isPrime to false. This means if no number divides, the isPrime remains unchanged (i.e. true)

And then finally, we check if the number is prime, and cout accordingly.

Now let us gear up our code. What we just implemented is just going to go inside a loop, since we now do this to the given range. And at this point, you should be able to understand it yourself.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    
    int range, count=0;

    cout << "Enter the number: ";
    cin >> range;

    for(int num = 2; num < range; num++) {
        bool isPrime = true;
        for(int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
            if(num%i == 0){
                // Not a prime number
                isPrime = false;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime) {
            cout << num << " is a prime number\n";
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << "There were total " << count << " prime numbers";
    return 0;
}
}
```

Note how I created the variable in the for loop itself, this is not just good practice because it reduces lines of code, but when you create the variable outside, it is accessible everywhere in that scope(everywhere in main() function here). But variables created in the above manner are only accessible inside the for loop.

Also, I saw you created way too many variables like `count`, I don't know what you used it for, I'm assuming you needed to count how many numbers are prime, so I implemented that as well.